# Is there a tool to measure which Grunt task takes long?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, pug, yeoman, stylus

I use [Yeoman Jade Generator](https://npmjs.org/package/generator-jade) with mostly default settings. When I run grunt build, I notice that its `htmlmin` task takes very long, about 5-10 minutes, though I only have one HTML page, FontAwesome font, a couple of JavaScript files and 20-40 images, so nothing extraordinary there in my files structure.

I wonder if there is some tool for Grunt that can show me which task takes how long to figure out the bottleneck? Or are there other ways to locate the potential slowness reason?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it but looks useful: https://github.com/sindresorhus/time-grunt. Also `--verbose` mode may display some useful information.